# Why when creating ray images and adding gap between them it's not adding any gaps at all?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Networking;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class SavedGamesSlots : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject saveSlotPrefab;
    public float gap;

    private GameObject slots;
    private string[] imagesToLoad;
    private RawImageInfo rawImageInfo;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        rawImageInfo = GetComponent<RawImageInfo>();

        string imagesFolder = Path.Combine(Application.dataPath + "/Saved Screenshots");
        if (!Directory.Exists(imagesFolder))
        {
            Directory.CreateDirectory(imagesFolder);
        }

        imagesToLoad = Directory.GetFiles(imagesFolder, "*.png");

        slots = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Slots Content");

        if (imagesToLoad.Length > 0 && slots != null)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < imagesToLoad.Length; i++)
            {
                var go = Instantiate(saveSlotPrefab);
                go.transform.SetParent(slots.transform);
                
                Texture2D thisTexture = new Texture2D(100, 100);
                string fileName = imagesToLoad[i];
                go.GetComponent<RawImageInfo>().FolderAndFileName = fileName;
                rawImageInfo.FolderAndFileName = fileName;
                byte[] bytes = File.ReadAllBytes(fileName);
                thisTexture.LoadImage(bytes);
                thisTexture.name = fileName;
                go.GetComponent<RawImage>().texture = thisTexture;
                var raw = go.GetComponent<RectTransform>();
                raw.anchoredPosition = new Vector3(i * gap, 6, 0);
            }
        }
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {

    }
}
```

This is the lines for the gaps :

```
var raw = go.GetComponent<RectTransform>();
raw.anchoredPosition = new Vector3(i * gap, 6, 0);
```

Now there is no gap between the raw images at all. There are two raw images in this case.
No gap between them and i want that the first gap will start from the left so the raw images will start from the left with a gap for example if i set gap to 3 then it will start with a gap from the left side and then 3 gap between each raw image and when getting to the end if there are more raw images start a new line under the first one with the same gaps.

[image: save system]

The scroll view settings :

[image: scroll view settings]

I see now that the created raw's Rect Transform is disabled and the only option that is enabled is the Z position of the raw :

[image: raw rect transform is disabled only z position enabled]

screenshot of the content :

[image: content]

screenshot of the viewport :

[image: viewport]

screenshot of the scroll view :

[image: scroll view]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need add the width of the image.

```
float x = 0f;

for (int i = 0; i < imagesToLoad.Length; i++)
{
    var raw = go.GetComponent<RectTransform>();
    raw.anchoredPosition = new Vector3(x, 6, 0);
    x += raw.sizeDelta.x + gap; // width + gap
}
```

Comment: i see now that when the raw is created the Rect Transform is disabled the only thing i can change in the Rect Transform is the Z position. not sure why.  i guess this is why the code is not working the answer.

Comment: i edited my question and added more screenshots.

Comment: Because there is a **Grid Layout Group** attached on the Content object. If you want to manually set the position, remove (or disable) it.